# Return Array of Unique Elements

Tags: java, arrays

I'm very new to Java and I'm having a hard time trying to add unique values from an old Array to my new Array, technically I have to return a new Array with unique elements without using sets.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] list = {1,2,1};
    double [] Arr = new double[list.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < list.length; x++) {
            if(list[i] != list[x]){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Question: how do you add them to your new Array?

**I changed it to:**

```
    int index = 1;
    int unique = 0;
    newArray[0] = list[0];
    while( index < list.length) {
        if(list[index] != list[index - 1]){
            unique = unique + 1;
            newArray[unique] = list[index];
        }
        index++;
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

Works now.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't executed this, but below code should give you fair idea of how it needs to be done

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[] list = {1,2,1};
    double [] Arr = new double[list.length];
    int uniqueIndex = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        boolean present = false;
        for(int x = 0; x < uniqueIndex; x++) {
            if(list[i] == Arr[x]){
                 present = true;
                 break;
            }
        }
        if(!present)
           Arr[uniqueIndex++] = list[i];
    }
}
```

The new array would have default 0 values at the end after removing duplicates, you may want to trim it, may be create new one with `System.arraycopy`

Answer (score 1):

Just because I can't help myself, here is another option using Java 8 features.  It's a lot more succinct than others, but probably isn't what your teacher is after.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  double[] list = {1, 2, 1};

  double[] arr = Arrays.stream(list).distinct().toArray();

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Comment: This is the proper answer.

Comment: Thank you! but that is not what the teacher wants. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach. A newbie should write the code himself.

1) Sort your array/list.

2) Traverse the array/list till length-1, and if list[i] != list[i+1], push list[i] to new list.

3) If list[length-1] != list[length], push list[length] to the new list.

Complexity: O(nlgn) + O(n)

Comment: You can solve it in O(n) time complexity if there is a limit on largest and smallest value in array and all values are integer.